# DomElement from ContextMenuHandler

Tags: jxbrowser

Is there away to get the DOMElement with my ContextMenuHandler when user right clicks on page?  I need to retrieve attribute information stored on element that I click on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Browser.getNodeAtPoint(int x, int y)` method to find `DOMNode` at the given location on the loaded document. The `x` and `y` you can get from `ContextMenuParams`. For example:

```
DOMNodeAtPoint nodeAtPoint = params.getBrowser().getNodeAtPoint(params.getLocation());
DOMNode node = nodeAtPoint.getNode();
```